# How to maintain the same pixel appearance, when rendering a exported image sequence

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, pixel-art

I need to import a animation png (with alpha) sequence into Blender, then put it on a geometry (a simple plane) to move some vertices (very subtle animation) and after that, export it again with the new deformation animation.
How can i maintain the same pixel ratio/animation when rendering the output? i don't want or need Blender to soften the edges for example.
*(i want to render this on render internal, with plain colors, not adding any kind of light)*
I also need to mention, the frame 0 need to be the same as the static image, with the same pixel appearance, without any 'filter' appeared.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say move some vertices, you think to what ? If you don't use the video sequence editor with exact frame ration in input as in output, your render will pass through a matrice that will recalculate each pixel, and it won't be the EXACT same pixel (there is anti aliasing and other things) If you are effraied of losing some detail, render 10% bigger depending on your needs.

Comment: With the vertices i mean the vertices in the 3D plane, imagine a 3D 'word' that has kind of 3d extruded vertices, and i want to move these, but just a little.

Comment: If you move slightly a vertex, it will have to resample new pixel to regenerate this change. 

Best you can do is turn into shadeless, change filmic to srgb (if it is what you need) and it will be ok for your needs i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine an image of 140x139 (this one : [image: 140x139pixel-image])

If you import in blender with images as plane addon, with emission or shadeless shader

And set your render output to the same resolution and framerate [image]

And add an orthographic camera above to the center of your image, with orthographic view
[[image]
[[image]

You can adjust the size by zooming a lot in a corner from the camera view (Numpad 0) and adjust the Orthographic Scale.
Set color management to standard to don't have filmic transformation
And sampling to 1 to avoid anti aliasing.
[image]

The resulting image shouldn't be different.(I checked on photoshop : [image])

However, if you want to move the plane (rotate, or distort) the pixel will change as the raster sample the same pixels to in the same location. It will rasterize the image depending on the new transform, some pixels may stay the same, but some others will change.

Example of a distorted image : [image: Rasterisation]